# Как написать обмен местами элементов в массиве?

Tags: java

В методе `swap` нужно написать так код, чтобы когда я задавал определенные числа `a` и `b` (позиции в массиве), он менял их местами. Например, массив `9 2 3 5 8 8 8 8 3 4`. Я задаю `1` и `2` - это значит, что числа на этих позициях меняются друг с другом. То есть становится `9 3 2 5 8 8 8 8 3 4`.

```java
public class App {
    int[] arr = new int[10];

    void start() {
        sluchaynoye();
        print();
        swap(0, 1);
    }

    void print() { //
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    int ran() { //
        return (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }

    void sluchaynoye() { //
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = ran();
        }
    }

    void swap(int a, int b) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void swap (int a, int b) {
    int c = arr[a];  // записываем первонач. значение arr[a] в переменную с 
    arr[a] = arr[b]; // в arr[a] записываем arr[b]
    arr[b] = c;      // в arr[b] записываем с (первонач. значение arr[a])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В нормальном виде это должно выглядеть так :

```
public class App {
    
    private final int[] arr;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //рандомный массив на 10 элементов, минимальное значение чисел в массиве - 0, максимальное - 10
        App app = new App(10, 0, 10);
        //а можем создать экземпляр класса, работающий с массивом, который мы передаем в конструкторе, а не с рандомным
        //App app = new App(new int[]{5,3,1,0,8});
        
        //выводим в консоль, для этого переопределяем метод toString()
        System.out.println(app);
        
        app.swap(0, 1);
                
        System.out.println(app);
    }

    public App(int[] arr) {
        this.arr=arr;
    }
    
    public App(int size, int origin, int bound) {
        this(new java.util.Random().ints(size, origin, bound).toArray());
    }
    
    public void swap(int index1, int index2) {
        int tmp = arr[index1];
        arr[index1] = arr[index2];
        arr[index2] = tmp;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //поскольку для массива метод toString() не переопределен, используем утилитный метод вывода массива в консоль
        return java.util.Arrays.toString(arr);
    }
    
}
```

если что-то непонятно - задавайте вопросы

Comment: Зачем вы весь остальной код привели? )

Comment: @Kromster а вы его сравните с кодом в вопрос и поймете

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду вопрос "в методе swap нужно написать так код", то он говорит только о методе swap. Остальной код к проблеме вопроса вообще не относится.

Comment: @Kromster нет, я имею в виду, что в приведенном коде проблем больше, чем реализация метода swap. дальше все зависит от вашего отношения к ситуации. если вы видите, что человек забивает шурупы и просит подать молоток, то у вас 2 пути. 1) подать молоток и пусть дальше забивает (суть его вопроса ведь была в том, чтобы молоток подать, а дальше его проблемы). 2) все таки дать отвертку (одновременно это не страхует от того, что он снова возьмет молоток). лично мне второй подход больше нравится (и это не значит, что я не читал вопроса). какой подход выбираете вы решать вам))

Comment: SO это всё же FAQ/Wiki по конкретным вопросам (например, как написать swap для массива), и не выполнение чужих заданий "от и до".